# Python - Type error upon evaluating string match

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to normalize some data. In my dataframe, if the columns begin with the same prefix, they belong together (fe. `ab_000` and `ab_001` belong together, however `ac_000` does not belong to the previous two). So I'm trying to normalize the belonging columns with an l1 normalization. For this, I have written:

```
def normalize(df):
    data = df.copy()
    to_work_with = []
    for i in range(0, len(data.columns) - 1):
        for j in range(0, len(data.columns) -1 ):  
            if data.columns[i][:2] == data.columns[j][:2]:  # error here
                to_work_with.append(data.columns[j])
        data[to_work_with] = nr(data[to_work_with],axis=1, norm='l1')
        to_work_with = []
    return data
```

However, in the line marked by the comment, I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If I just run

```
data.columns[1][:2] == data.columns[2][:2]
```

It returns a `False`, no error. What am I missing?

[EDIT]
Apparantly it runs for a while before the error is produced. By adding a `print(data.columns[j][:2])` right before the comparison, I get the output:

[image]

Sample data:

```
    aa_000  ab_000  ac_000  ad_000  ae_000  af_000  af_001  af_002  af_003  af_004  ... ed_004  ed_005  ed_006  ed_007  ed_008  ed_009  ee_000  ef_000  eg_000  classN
0   76698   NaN 2.130706e+09    280.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 493384.0    721044.0    469792.0    339156.0    157956.0    73224.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -1
1   33058   NaN 0.000000e+00    NaN 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 178064.0    293306.0    245416.0    133654.0    81140.0 97576.0 1500.0  0.0 0.0 -1
2   41040   NaN 2.280000e+02    100.0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 159812.0    423992.0    409564.0    320746.0    158022.0    95128.0 514.0   0.0 0.0 -1
```

Comment: Are you sure that all of these columns are collections, and not `int`s? Try inserting `print(data.columns[j][:2])` right before the line that's giving errors.

Comment: Yes, I'm positive, it even runs for a while. I'll update the post with a pic.

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of the data that is being processed in the function?

Comment: SuperBiasedMan is right, we can’t really help you if we don’t know the structure of `data.columns`. Sounds like your issue is you have one too few levels of nesting somewhere in your list structures though.

Comment: can you print `data.columns[i]` too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of your data.columns is type int.

**getitem**() is called when you use operator [].

For example, when `tmp = columns[2]`, `columns.__getitem__(2)` is called.